# What is the process to migrate the baker/endorser nodes to another server?

Tags: baker, endorser

In case of hardware/network failure in cloud server what is the process to migrate baker and endorser to the new server?

How baker can be punished for downtime during the migration process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For high availability, you should already have a 2nd tezos-node running and sync'd with the network. If you need to move baking operations to the backup server, best is to copy the `~/.tezos-client/` directory from server A to server B. Then you can start the baker/endorser on server B.

You will be punished **HARD** if you double bake or double endorse so make sure that you **NEVER** run both bakers at the same time. If your baker is offline when it is your turn to bake, you lose 40 XTZ reward for missing the bake, 1.25 xtz lost for missed endorsements.

Comment: What if we lost the storage as well on the server? Is there any way we can srtart baker on another server without copying the folder from one to another?

Comment: Certainly, just download a snapshot from any of the public places. Please note that ~/.tezos-client/ is NOT the data directory for tezos node (which is at ~/.tezos-node/). The reason to copy the client folder is to make sure any nonces you need to reveal in the next cycle are saved, plus your baking keys are in there too.

Comment: okay so what I have to do is take snapshot from any online and download it in server then just put tezos-client directory at usr/share/doc/tezos-client is that right what you suggesting? I can see the changelog.Debian.gz and copyright inside the tezos-client folder and same data in tezos-node folder which is also at /usr/share/doc/tezos-node

Comment: The tezos-client contains 3 files public_key_hashs,public_keys and secret_keys. That's the only file we need to transfer right?

Comment: got sew files here in the tezos-client folder which are blocks,config,endorsements,public_key_hashs,public_keys,secret_keys and wallet_lock

Comment: Copy all of those files to your backup server.